# Cannot load English language model from spacy (Jupyter Notebook | Python 3.9)

Tags: python, nlp, jupyter, conda, spacy

I am using *Jupyter Notebook* on a Python 3.9 Anaconda virtual environment. My aim is to load the English language model *"en_core_web_sm"* from the `spacy` package. I must note that the language model is already installed. Thus, I simply write:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm") # We may need to install the language model first
```

I get the following error:

> ImportError: blis.cy does not export expected C function sgemm

In the context of the following output:

> ~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_12804\1341815734.py in 
> 1 import spacy
> 2
> 3 nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm") # We may need to install the language model first
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\spacy_*init*_.py in 
> 4
> 5 # set library-specific custom warning handling before doing anything else
> 6 from .errors import setup_default_warnings
> 7
> 8 setup_default_warnings()  # noqa: E402
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\spacy\errors.py in 
> 1 import warnings
> 2 from .compat import Literal
> 3
> 4
> 5 class ErrorsWithCodes(type):
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\spacy\compat.py in 
> 36     from catalogue import _importlib_metadata as importlib_metadata  # type: ignore[no-redef]    # noqa: F401
> 37
> 38 from thinc.api import Optimizer  # noqa: F401
> 39
> 40 pickle = pickle
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\thinc\api.py in 
> 1 from .config import Config, registry, ConfigValidationError
> 2 from .initializers import normal_init, uniform_init, glorot_uniform_init, zero_init
> 3 from .initializers import configure_normal_init
> 4 from .loss import CategoricalCrossentropy, L2Distance, CosineDistance
> 5 from .loss import SequenceCategoricalCrossentropy
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\thinc\initializers.py in 
> 2 import numpy
> 3
> 4 from .backends import Ops
> 5 from .config import registry
> 6 from .types import FloatsXd, Shape
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\thinc\backends_*init*_.py in 
> 5 import threading
> 6
> 7 from .ops import Ops
> 8 from .cupy_ops import CupyOps
> 9 from .numpy_ops import NumpyOps
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\thinc\backends\ops.py in 
> 14 from ..util import get_array_module, is_xp_array, to_numpy
> 15
> 16 from .cblas import CBlas
> 17
> 18 ArrayT = TypeVar("ArrayT", bound=ArrayXd)
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\thinc\backends\cblas.pyx in init thinc.backends.cblas()
>
> ImportError: blis.cy does not export expected C function sgemm

Another user recently had my same problem. In [this comment](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/12138#discussioncomment-4754406), user [danieldk](https://github.com/danieldk) answered:

> It looks like the installed blis version is too old for the installed thinc version. Could you give the output of conda list and check that there are no broken requirements with pip check?

However, the user did not offer further replies, and the thread was closed without a resolution. I ran `pip check` myself, and I can confirm there are no broken requirements. The installed `blis` version is `0.7.9`.

What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Download it like this: `!python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`.